# Rails: Is there any way to invoke helper method from console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails, I would like to call helper method define in `application_helper.rb` from rails console directly, same as we do for model methods.

I have helper method defined as

```
 module ApplicationHelper

    def user_name(user)
        if user.is_admin?
            user.customer.name
        else
            user.name
        end
    end

end
```

while calling helper method I am getting following error

```
2.3.1 :002 > user_name(user)
NoMethodError: undefined method `user_name' for main:Object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use helper method from rails console

```
user = User.first

helper.user_name(user)
```